# ActiveRecord extension to find next / previous record(s) in one query

Tags: ruby, sql, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I just wrote this gem [order_query](https://github.com/glebm/order_query) to find next or previous records relative to the record assuming a (possibly complex) `ORDER BY` over the records. For example, this is needed to show a link to the next result from the current search result page.

> The gem is used like so:
>
> ```
> class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
>   include OrderQuery
>   order_query :order_display, [
>     [:priority, %w(high medium low)],
>     [:valid_votes_count, :desc, sql: '(votes - suspicious_votes)'],
>     [:updated_at, :desc],
>     [:id, :desc]
>   ]
>   def valid_votes_count
>     votes - suspicious_votes
>   end
> end
>
> Issue.order_display         #=> ActiveRecord::Relation<...>
> Issue.reverse_order_display #=> ActiveRecord::Relation<...>
>
> p = Issue.find(31).order_display(scope) # scope default: Issue.all
> p.items_before  #=> ActiveRecord::Relation<...>
> p.prev_item     #=> Issue<...>
> p.position      #=> 5
> p.next_item     #=> Issue<...>
> p.items_after   #=> ActiveRecord::Relation<...>
> ```
>
> [Read more](https://github.com/glebm/order_query)

The code gets a [complex method warning from CodeClimate](https://codeclimate.com/github/glebm/order_query/OrderQuery%3a%3aRelativeOrder), and I agree: it does not look easy to comprehend.

Can this be done better?

This is [the code](https://github.com/glebm/order_query/blob/master/lib/order_query/relative_order.rb#L60) that constructs the query:

```
# @param [:before or :after] mode
def build_query(mode)
  # The next element will be the first one among elements with lesser order
  build_query_factor(
      order.map { |o| where_relative(o, mode) },
      order.map { |o| where_eq(o) }
  )
end

# @param [Array] x query conditions
# @param [Array] y query conditions
# @return [query, query_args] The resulting query is as follows:
#   x0 | y0 &
#      (x1 | y1 &
#        (x2 | y2 &
#          (x3 | y3 & ... )))
#
# Explanation:
#
#   To narrow the result to only the records that come before / after the current one, build_query passes
#   the values of x and y so that:
#
#   x matches order criteria with values that come after the current record.
#   y matches order criteria with values equal to the current record's value, for resolving ties.
#
def build_query_factor(x, y, i = 0, n = x.length)
  q = []

  x_cond = [x[i][0].presence, x[i][1]]
  q << x_cond if x_cond[0]

  if i >= 1
    q << ['AND'] << y[i - 1]
  end

  if i < n - 1
    q << ['OR'] if x_cond[0]
    nested = build_query_factor(x, y, i + 1)
    q << ["(#{nested[0]})", nested[1]]
  end

  [q.map { |e| e[0] }.join(' '),
   q.map { |e| e[1] }.compact.reduce(:+) || []]
end

EMPTY_FILTER = ['', []]

def where_eq(spec)
  ["#{spec.col_name_sql} = ?", [values[spec.name]]]
end

# @param [:before or :after] mode
def where_relative(spec, mode)
  ord   = spec.order
  value = values[spec.name]
  if ord.is_a?(Array)
    # ord is an array of values, ordered first to last, e.g.
    # all up to current
    pos    = ord.index(value)
    values = mode == :after ? ord.from(pos + 1) : ord.first(pos) if pos
    # if current not in result set, do not apply filter
    return EMPTY_FILTER unless values.present?
    ["#{spec.col_name_sql} IN (?)", [values]]
  else
    # ord is :asc or :desc
    op = {before: {asc: '<', desc: '>'}, after: {asc: '>', desc: '<'}}[mode][ord || :asc]
    ["#{spec.col_name_sql} #{op} ?", [value]]
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe it would be better if you pasted in your question the actual code you want us to review.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will stick to reviewing the code you've posted, although it seems tied to other code.

First of all: Use descriptive variable names. `x`, `y`, `q`, and so forth aren't great for legibility. Use `query`, `position` and similar full words. Especially since you're dealing with complex nested arrays.

There also seems to be some logical issues/dangerous assumptions. I don't know if you check/sanitize your input elsewhere, but if you don't things will get weird. E.g.:

```
# This will fail if x[i] is nil
x_cond = [x[i][0].presence, x[i][1]]

q << x_cond if x_cond[0]

if i >= 1
  # 1. This *may* append ["AND"] etc. directly to an empty array,
  #    if x_cond[0] was nil above, resulting in a nonsense query.
  # 2. This will fail if y.count < i - 1
  q << ['AND'] << y[i - 1]
end
```

In other words, if `x_cond[0]` isn't present, you don't append anything to the array. Yet the following `if` block assumes that something definitely was appended. And there's no check for the length of `y` so `y[i - 1]` may fail. And `x[i][0].presence` will fail if `x[i]` is nil to begin with.

I also see some (dangerous) redundancy, like the `n = x.length` method parameter. There's no reason for this to be a method parameter. In fact, it's detrimental, because the `n` value is never checked, so you can pass any value like `n = -42` which wouldn't make sense.

Moreover, **the code doesn't actually match its description**: Your comment for `build_query_factory` states that the result should be something like:

```
x0 OR y0 AND (x1 OR y1 AND (x3 OR y3))
```

but the method returns:

```
x1 OR (x2 AND y1 OR (x3 AND y2))
```

Notice that a) the structure is very different, and b) `y3` doesn't even appear.

---

Now, assuming that you want the result you give as an example in the comment (and not the result the method actually returns), I would do something like this:

```
def build_nested_query(x, y)
  # zip the two arrays (x, y, x, y, x, y, ...)
  ordered = x.zip(y)

  # split into conditions and parameters
  ordered = ordered.map do |x, y|
    [ [x.first, y.first], [x.second, y.second] ] # still confusing, to be honest
  end

  conditions = ordered.map(&:first)
  parameters = ordered.map(&:second).flatten # thanks to ActiveSupport for Array#second, by the way

  [ nest_conditions(conditions) , parameters ]
end

def nest_conditions(conditions)
  # create "x OR y" string
  branch = conditions.first
  branch = branch.join(" OR ")

  # nest the remaining recursively, appending them with " AND "
  remaining = conditions[1..-1]
  if remaining.any?
    nested = nest_conditions(remaining)
    branch += " AND (#{nested})"
  end

  branch
end
```

That'll do something like this:

```
x = [["x1", [:x1]], ["x2", [:x2]], ["x3", [:x3]]]
y = [["y1", [:y1]], ["y2", [:y2]], ["y3", [:y3]]]

query = build_nested_query(x, y)
query[0] #=> "x1 OR y1 AND (x2 OR y2 AND (x3 OR y3))"
query[1] #=> [:x1, :y1, :x2, :y2, :x3, :y3]
```

Which I believe is what you want. You'll want to do some sanity-checking/sanitizing of `x` and `y` beforehand, to make sure they make sense.

Of course, if you find a better way to supply the method parameters in the first place, the code can be cleaned up even more.

I would also consider encapsulating conditions and parameters somehow to avoid the non-descriptive `[0]` and `[1]` (or `first`/`second`) stuff in favor of something more descriptive (Rails no doubt already has an internal class for this structure. Otherwise, a simple `Struct`-based class should do.)

---

I haven't looked closely at `where_relative`, but again I see some strange logic:

```
def where_relative(spec, mode)
  ord = spec.order

  # I assume `values` is an instance variable?
  # Anyway, why assign `value` here? It's only used in
  # the else-block, and so should be assigned there
  value = values[spec.name]

  if ord.is_a?(Array)

    # ...

    # Wait, now you're assigning something to `values`?
    values = mode == :after ? ord.from(pos + 1) : ord.first(pos) if pos

    # and apparently, that something can be nil, since you're
    # checking for that here - but you didn't check for that
    # before you called `values[spec.name]` above
    return EMPTY_FILTER unless values.present?

    # ...

  else

    # ...

    # And here you use `value` (i.e. values[spec.name])
    ["#{spec.col_name_sql} #{op} ?", [value]]

  end
end
```

Now, I admit I don't know the exact sequence of events, but the above looks/smells like dangerous assumptions and nasty side effects. If the method is called several times per object instantiation, results get unpredictable. First time it's called, I assume `values` is set to something. But it might get set to `nil` by the method. This will cause the next call to the method to crash on `values[spec.name]`. If the method is so completely dependent on `values`, it should be a parameter.

Lastly, this line should really be reworked:

```
values = mode == :after ? ord.from(pos + 1) : ord.first(pos) if pos
```

Don't use a ternary and postfixed `if` on the same line - it's very confusing.

Comment: Zipping arrays before `nest_conditions` is a clever move that simplifies everything greatly, thanks :) Refactoring for now, will get back when done

Comment: I've refactored, and you can see the result [here](https://github.com/glebm/order_query/commit/cf545212a75ec237a5cfcd9649b57df1ab9bfa9d). CodeClimate now reports A (4.0, highest score) too!

Comment: @glebm Neat! Glad it helped

Comment: :D By the way, I have another question about this gem's relevance [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440601/given-a-record-and-order-conditions-find-records-after-or-before)

Comment: Recognized a `foldr` and reduced the method down to just a few lines of code https://github.com/glebm/order_query/blob/e3522f061036a172a24f70e8882a616e2cd315be/lib/order_query/sql/where.rb#L41-L48